# Flutter: How to use HapticFeedback

Tags: flutter, dart, haptic-feedback

I have imported

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

and then called

```
HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
```

nothing happens. What do I need to do to get it working?
I am testing with the latest Flutter version 1.6.6 on a Galaxy S8 running Android 9.0

Comment: According to the official doc (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/HapticFeedback/lightImpact.html) it should work on Android as well. Did you try one of the other static methods like selectionClick? If it still doesn't work maybe you could provide a code sample where it doesn't work in your case

Comment: Here is my answer for both android and ios: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413987/how-to-implement-vibration-with-flutter-for-both-android-and-ios/63622425#63622425

Answer (score 31):

Please make sure that Vibration feedback is enabled on the android device, and make sure to add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml.
See more info here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33750

Comment: @ChiragChopra please make sure that Vibration feedback is enabled on the device, see this comment - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33750#issuecomment-499703756

Answer (score 14):

`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

1. import the services package

then inside onTap method

`onTap: () {
    Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: data));
    HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
}`

it worked for me.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, eventually I had to use Vibrate package but I'm wondering why this native implementation doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 12):

Please also check whether, `Vibration feedback` setting was enabled on the device or not . I faced same issue but later found out that Haptic Feedback vibration was off on my device (I was testing it in Android 9) so, make sure to enable it.

To enable it,

> Go to settings>sound&vibration>touch vibration

Comment: Thank you that was my issue, my Samsung S21 search in settings for system vibration -> touch interactions

Answer (score 8):

This is helped me

First Go to AndroidManifest and add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

If the Flutter app is running stop it and run it again.
Then use this code

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

And in Ontap or OnPressed Method

```
Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData());
HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
```

That's all

Answer (score 6):

Try using this for Android:

```
Feedback.forTap(context);
```

More info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Feedback-class.html

Answer (score 6):

Reading the function description it says:

"On Android, this uses `HapticFeedbackConstants.KEYBOARD_TAP`."

If the vibrations for the keyboard or 'haptic feedback for tap' are turned off (in the phone's settings), calling `HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();` will not have an effect.

To fix the problem one would have to turn on `Touch vibration` in the phone's settings.

Answer (score -3):

If only activating  touch vibration on phone doesn't solve the issue , try switching between Vibrate on tap modes.Default setting is `Off`.

```
Vibrate on tap (Settings -Off(default),Ligh,Medium,Strong)
```