# How to implement vibration with Flutter for both Android and iOS?

Tags: flutter, dart, vibration

Using Flutter I am trying to implement vibration on a button click.

I find it surprisingly difficult to be honest. I've tried using the following packages unsuccessfully:
[vibration](https://pub.dev/packages/vibration) and [vibrate](https://pub.dev/packages/vibrate) but they just do not vibrate (talking here about the real devices not emulators/simulators).

Is there a guide with clear examples on how to implement vibration on iOS and Android devices with Flutter?

Thanks,
Mihai

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Found a way using `HapticFeedback.vibrate()`. It works for both iOS and Android. See more details with code example and other settings on this [post][1]: [Flutter: How to use HapticFeedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402196/flutter-how-to-use-hapticfeedback)

Comment: I've created a quick tutorial for implementing vibration with Flutter, in case you struggle with it. Have a look: https://medium.com/tagmalogic/implement-vibration-with-flutter-c0a7d2d4007?source=friends_link&sk=6976429f156a8a7095e939f85be62f3e

Comment: Thanks, do you know why it wouldn't work for a Samsung S8? None of the methods work. It's funny because using a plugin like Vibrate at least a few of the vibration methods work. This is on Android 9 btw, and we have the manifest entry.

Comment: @DarkNeuron  maybe worth having a look in `Settings` then `Sounds and vibration` and then `Vibration feedback` and turn that on if not done already.

Comment: @Miha That was turned on, but we found another setting called "Touch vibration". So there's effectively 2 settings for vibrations. With Touch vibration turned on, some of the vibrate functions worked. I think it was "heavy" and "selection" that didn't.

Comment: I dont think HapticFeedback support Flutter web correct?

Answer (score 23):

The simplest solution for Flutter 2021

**1) Import standard services:**

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

**2) Use:**

```
HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
```

or `lightImpact`, or `heavyImpact`

**3) Don't forget to add this at Android Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

**BONUS) Play "Click" Sound:**

```
SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click);
```

Comment: medium, and heavyImpact() method does not work for me.

Comment: to use "SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click);", do I need to add a special Permission in Android Manifest?

Answer (score 7):

I will recommend to use [flutter_vibrate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vibrate), it will work for both ios/ android. Simplier setup and works very well.

1. Just add flutter_vibrate as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.

   dependencies:
   vibration: ^1.3.0
2. Make sure you add the following permissions to your Android Manifest
3. Import the package:

   import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';

Examples:

Vibrate for default 500ms:

```
Vibration.vibrate();
```

Vibrate for 1000ms:

```
Vibration.vibrate(duration: 1000);
```

Pattern: wait 0.5s, vibrate 1s, wait 0.5s, vibrate 2s, wait 0.5s, vibrate 3s, wait 0.5s, vibrate 0.5s:

```
Vibration.vibrate(pattern: [500, 1000, 500, 2000, 500, 3000, 500, 500]);
```

Pattern: wait 0.5s, vibrate 1s, wait 0.5s, vibrate 2s, wait 0.5s, vibrate 3s, wait 0.5s, vibrate 0.5s':

```
Vibration.vibrate( pattern: [500, 1000, 500, 2000, 500, 3000, 500, 500], intensities: [128, 255, 64, 255]);
```

**Android**

The VIBRATE permission is required in AndroidManifest.xml.

Supports vibration with duration and pattern. On Android 8 (Oreo) and above, uses the [VibrationEffect][1] class. For the rest of the usage instructions, see [Vibrator][1] class documentation.

**iOS**

Supports vibration with duration and pattern on CoreHaptics devices. On older devices, the pattern is emulated with 500ms long vibrations. You can check whether the current device has CoreHaptics support using [hasCustomVibrationsSupport](https://pub.dev/documentation/vibration/latest/#hasCustomVibrationsSupport).

Comment: I've tried this package. It throws too many runtime errors

Comment: I am using   'package:vibration/vibration.dart' it's much more simplier, after import just call      Vibration.vibrate(duration: 200);

Comment: the new functions to call is Vibrate.vibrate();

Comment: best answer! most answers for Vibration package throw runtime errors. thanks!!!!

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to add `vibrate:` as a dependency to your `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  vibrate:
```

After this, you need to import the package in the class that you are using.

```
// Import package
import 'package:vibrate/vibrate.dart';
```

Now you can this for **vibration**:

```
// Check if the device can vibrate
bool canVibrate = await Vibrate.canVibrate;

// Vibrate
// Vibration duration is a constant 500ms because
// it cannot be set to a specific duration on iOS.
Vibrate.vibrate();

// Vibrate with pauses between each vibration
final Iterable<Duration> pauses = [
    const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
];
// vibrate - sleep 0.5s - vibrate - sleep 1s - vibrate - sleep 0.5s - vibrate
Vibrate.vibrateWithPauses(pauses);
```

or for **haptic feedback**:

```
// Choose from any of these available methods
enum FeedbackType {
  success,
  error,
  warning,
  selection,
  impact,
  heavy,
  medium,
  light
}

var _type = FeedbackType.impact;
Vibrate.feedback(_type);
```

Source: https://github.com/clovisnicolas/flutter_vibrate

Comment: Can you please share a .dart file with a working example. Cannot figure out how to implement the code above. I've added dependencies in the .yaml file above. I was even using the example provided in the plugin here `https://github.com/clovisnicolas/flutter_vibrate/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart` but when running on iOS (iPhone 7 iOS 12.1.4) I get the following error: `Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    ....

Finished with error: Error running pod install`

Comment: full error message: `Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] `<PBXGroup UUID=`xxx`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `xxx` for attribute: `children`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Finished with error: Error running pod install`

Comment: Just a follow up on this @BastianMeyer just in case you know a way to implement HapticFeedback in Flutter for Android (not using the plugin above). I can get it working for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vibrate/vibrate.dart';

// Note:
// Make sure you add the following permissions to your Android Manifest
// <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
// 
// In pubspec.yaml file, add following dependency
// dependencies:
//   vibrate: ^0.0.4

class TestVibration extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestVibrationState createState() => _TestVibrationState();
}

class _TestVibrationState extends State<TestVibration> {

  bool canVibrate = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkIfVibrate();
  }
  _checkIfVibrate() async {
    // check if device can vibrate
    canVibrate = await Vibrate.canVibrate;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Vibrate'),
        onPressed: (){
          // FeedbackTypes -> {success, error, warning, selection, impact, heavy, medium, light}
          _getVibration(FeedbackType.warning);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _getVibration(feedbackType) async {
    if (canVibrate) {
      Vibrate.feedback(feedbackType);
      // Vibrate.vibrate();   // Try this too!
    }
  }
}
```